# Refresh listview in fragment upon returning from fragment detail

Tags: android, listview, refresh, fragment, onactivityresult

My application has a principal activity with an action bar and a tabs menu.

Every tab is a fragment with a listview.

When I click in listview, fragment detail is open.

When I click the back button, listview appears but sometimes not all the elements appear; some of them appear in white.

If I touch refresh, it appears fine.

The `onActivityResult` doesn't execute.

My idea was to do `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` from refresh.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try use

```
    public void onResume() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        fillListView();
    }
```

this method will be called every time you return from detail fragment.

Hope it Helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
The onActivityResult doesn't execut
```

Once I had same problem i did someting like this

In `onBackPressed` your code must be before `super.onBackPressed`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onBack_My_Code(); // YOUR CODE HERE
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBack_My_Code(); // YOUR CODE HERE
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return false;
}
```

If above code dosen't work then `Armaan Stranger` is correct. You can refersh list in `on resume`.